# What are my options when upgrading my MacBookPro to 4GB RAM.

Tags: upgrade, memory, macbook-pro

My questions are:

1. Where to buy it and what to buy? I have heard that this RAM is
   generic enough and it does not have to come from Apple.
2. Can I reuse my existing stick(s)? Would I have a single 2GB module, or 2 x 1GB modules?
3. If I have 2GB already, is it a good idea to have one old stick and one new one? Which one is better placed at the top and which one at the bottom? Let me know what questions you have.

My computer's info:

**Hardware Overview:**

```
  Model Name           :    MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier     :    MacBookPro3,1
  Processor Name       :    Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed      :    2.4 GHz
  Number Of Processors :    1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache             :    4 MB
  Memory               :    2 GB
  Bus Speed            :    800 MHz
  Boot ROM Version     :    MBP31.0070.B07
  SMC Version (system) :    1.16f11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro) that Macbook model has 2x 1GB SO-DIMMs:

"2 GB (two 1 GB) of 667 MHz PC2-5300 DDR2 SO-DIMM SDRAM"

So you're going to have to replace both (2 sockets) with 2GB DIMMs to get your 4GB.

Any generic RAM matching those specs should work fine.  [Here's an example](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/PartsInfo.asp?root=us&LinkBack=http://www.kingston.com&ktcpartno=KVR667D2S5K2/4G) of a 'generic' 4GB "kit" from Kingston's ValueRAM line.

HTH...

Comment: Thanks, but something does not add up - my Front Side Bus freq is 800 MHz, not 667 MHz. There were different versions of MacBookPro. I bought mine in October, 2007.

Comment: FSB frequency is not the same as RAM frequency.  FSB is the speed between CPU and chip-set and in today's (and even 2007's) chip-sets these numbers don't need to (and often don't) match.  If you look at the Wikipedia link I provided it shows that the FSB of your model it 800MHz, but the RAM is 667MHz. HTH :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what the apple manual says about upgrading memory for the macbookpro3,1:

"Both memory slots can accept an SDRAM module that meets the 
following specifications:

- Double Data Rate Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Module (DDR SO-DIMM) format
- 1.25 inch or smaller
- 1 GB or 2 GB
- 200-pin
- PC2-5300 DDR2 667 MHz Type RAM"

Source: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/MacBookPro_Late_2007_2.4_2.2GHz_UG.pdf

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search?DeviceType=3&Mfr=APP&Line=MacBook%20Pro%20%28DDR2%29&Model=37981

You can use original 1GB
You can add another 1GB
Or replace with 2x2GB

1x2GB is more expensive and slower than extra 1GB